# WatchKit: Setting WKInterfaceImage programmatically

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I want to set my UIImage to WKInterfaceImage, but the simulator shows only black screen.
It works OK using  `setImageNamed: NSString*` method, but not with `setImage: UIImage*` . My file1.png is added to "(App Name) WatchKit App" folder.

```
- (void)willActivate {
   [self.imageView1 setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"file1"]]; // doesn't work
   [self.imageView1 setImageNamed: @"file1"]; // works OK
    [super willActivate];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Everything is working as expected.

`file1` is in your WatchKit App folder, which means it is on the *watch*.

Calling `[UIImage imageNamed:]` loads from the main bundle, which doesn't contain `file1`, so you get `nil`.

The way you are doing this is correct. `setImageNamed:` will look for images on the Watch first, then in the cache.

Comment: I wish Xcode would give you a warning when you try to do this in a watchkit extension.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]` from your extension will always return `nil` for a cached image. The image is cached on the watch — not in your extension.

Once an image is cached, it allows you to set a WKInterfaceImage using the `[WKInterfaceImage setImageNamed:]` method.